# PHP - What are PHP routing concepts I need to know to use routing libraries?

Tags: php, routes

I'm trying to get simple routing running using [Klein](https://github.com/klein/klein.php). I tried to run the simplest example:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$klein = new \Klein\Klein();

$klein->respond('GET', '/hello-world', function () {
    return 'Hello World!';
});

$klein->dispatch();
```

When I go to `localhost/mysitedomain/hello-world` in my browser, I just get an HttpException: `Fatal error: Uncaught Klein\Exceptions\HttpException in C:\xampp-portable-win32-7.2.9-0-VC15\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\vendor\klein\klein\src\Klein\Exceptions\HttpException.php on line 36`.

I read through the docs, and even other routing libraries but it seems like there's more to it than this. There's concepts like:

- Matching
- Responding
- Rendering
- Routing
- Views
- Controllers
- Actions

I was just hoping to get a function callback called when I go to a certain route, but I don't know what the reason for the exception is. Do I need to match first? Then respond? Then render?

I've tried the [dispatch](https://github.com/noodlehaus/dispatch) library and while I don't get errors in that one, the route callback never gets called.

I have no idea how these routing libraries work. **How do I get a simple working route with Klein?**

Comment: The httpexception seems to be caused by 404/405, but have no idea why.

Comment: You define `/hello-world` but attempt to load `/mysitedomain/hello-world` (I don't know neither the library nor your setup so I don't know if that's a problem). In any case, [that line of code](https://github.com/klein/klein.php/blob/master/src/Klein/Exceptions/HttpException.php#L36) throws an HTTP status code and it'd be nice to know which one (though I presume it's 404 Not Found); you can either catch and print the exception or check the browser "Network" pane.

Answer (score 1):

The Klein.php router seems to be broken/outdated. Last commit was 3 years ago, so i don't think there will be any updates soon.

For beginners i can recommend using [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/). It has more functions than routing, but you can just use the routing part and ignore the rest without any problems.

Comment: In fact Slim uses a third-party routing library: [FastRoute](https://packagist.org/packages/nikic/fast-route)